# how to get items purchased by customer with stripe on success page

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I struggle getting onformation about the purchase the customer just made when they are redirected back to the `success` page, after completing (successfully) checkout.

There is no information in the session object about what they just bought 5s ago!

How to get that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making several seperate API calls to get the customer, to get their history from the past certain amount of time, you can ask the API to return the `line_items` in the first request to retrieve the session object.

Bad

```
router.get('/success', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), async (req, res) => {

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.sessionId);
    
  // More requests, etc..
}
```

Better

```
router.get('/success', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), async (req, res) => {

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.sessionId, {
    expand: ['line_items'],
  });
    
  // etc..
}
```

This gives you back what they just purchased, so you can congratulate them on the success page much more easily.