# Stripe success page trying to get details from session_id

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to just retrieve the details from a successful transaction from Stripe in php. The official documentation tells me to install and use Slim, something I can't do in my current situation.

So far I've got the following code which throws me a report of some kind, but i don't fully understand what i'm looking at and I'm not sure where to go from here, or even if I'm getting the right information back in the first place!

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

require_once('../../stripe/init.php');

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  '[my test key]'
);
$stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve(
  $_GET['session_id'],
  []
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($stripe);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

this give me the following:

```
  Stripe\Service\Checkout\SessionService Object
(
    [client:protected] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
        (
            [coreServiceFactory:Stripe\StripeClient:private] => Stripe\Service\CoreServiceFactory Object
                (
                    [client:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [services:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Array
                        (
                            [checkout] => Stripe\Service\Checkout\CheckoutServiceFactory Object
                                (
                                    [client:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
 *RECURSION*
                                    [services:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [sessions] => Stripe\Service\Checkout\SessionService Object
 *RECURSION*
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [config:Stripe\BaseStripeClient:private] => Array
                (
                    [api_key] => [my_api_key]
                    [client_id] => 
                    [stripe_account] => 
                    [stripe_version] => 
                    [api_base] => https://api.stripe.com
                    [connect_base] => https://connect.stripe.com
                    [files_base] => https://files.stripe.com
                )

            [defaultOpts:Stripe\BaseStripeClient:private] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
                (
                    [apiKey] => 
                    [headers] => Array
                        (
                            [Stripe-Account] => 
                            [Stripe-Version] => 
                        )

                    [apiBase] => 
                )

        )

    [streamingClient:protected] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
        (
            [coreServiceFactory:Stripe\StripeClient:private] => Stripe\Service\CoreServiceFactory Object
                (
                    [client:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [services:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Array
                        (
                            [checkout] => Stripe\Service\Checkout\CheckoutServiceFactory Object
                                (
                                    [client:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
 *RECURSION*
                                    [services:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [sessions] => Stripe\Service\Checkout\SessionService Object
 *RECURSION*
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [config:Stripe\BaseStripeClient:private] => Array
                (
                    [api_key] => [my_api_key]
                    [client_id] => 
                    [stripe_account] => 
                    [stripe_version] => 
                    [api_base] => https://api.stripe.com
                    [connect_base] => https://connect.stripe.com
                    [files_base] => https://files.stripe.com
                )

            [defaultOpts:Stripe\BaseStripeClient:private] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
                (
                    [apiKey] => 
                    [headers] => Array
                        (
                            [Stripe-Account] => 
                            [Stripe-Version] => 
                        )

                    [apiBase] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Have a look here, perhaps?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777795/130230

Comment: I saw that before I posted but isn't that node.js? Plus I'll be honest, I can't even read that to translate it into php.

Comment: It is, but the Stripe API should be very similar for the PHP client..

Comment: Ok, but I still can't translate that to php. I get the basic idea and tried with: `$stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve(
  $_GET['session_id'],
  ['line-items']
);` but it didn't work.

Comment: I needed to add that `expand` object name. Perhaps you need something similar?

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_Your_Test_Key');

$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve($_GET['session_id']);
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($session->customer);

print_r($customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out based on the code I originally had. Here it is so other people don't have to go through the frustration I had:

```
require_once('../../stripe/init.php');

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  '{{my api key}}'
);
$line_items = $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve(
  $_GET['session_id'],
  []
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($line_items);
echo "</pre>";
```

I just needed to put the retrieve into an object, then I can output that object in the form of a json. Or something like that anyway. You'll know what I mean when you try it.